# How to deploy artifact to nexus with maven to custom path/file name without long classpath

Tags: maven, deployment, jar, nexus

I want to deploy my jar to nexus repository to custom directory and file name without other files.

Default behavior is to deploy to full class path like `REPONAME/com/vendor/artifact/version/classname-version.jar`

I want do deploy it always to `REPONAME/servicename/servicename.jar` and I not need any other files like `pom.xml` and other.

My `pom.xml` deploy section:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>nexus</serverId>
                <nexusUrl>https://nexusurl.com</nexusUrl>
                <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                <repositoryDirectory>REPO1</repositoryDirectory>
                <pomFile></pomFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://nexusurl.com/repository/ESB_TI/REPO1</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Versions</name>
        <url>https://nexusurl.com/repository/ESB_TI/REPO1</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Please explain why you need that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

A Maven repository has a fixed directory structure which cannot be changed.

If you just want to put a file at an arbitrary path, copy it to the server and use an Apache to provide it.